# ASP.NET WebAPI Connect to database in another project (WinForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I have Windows Forms project and database in it. Then I have to create ASP.NET WebAPI project which must have access to database in my Windows Forms project. I tried to used model EDM for build model based on this database and at the same time connect to database from Windows Forms. But this way wrong, because database just copy into WebAPI project, and if database had changed in Windows Forms project, this changes are not visible in WebAPI project. How can I simplY connect from WebAPI to database that located in Windows Forms?

Comment: How is the database stored for the Windows Forms app?

Comment: @MartinZikmund i used SQL Server and she located in bin/debug directory(mdf file).

Comment: Use a database instance - eg a centralised server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Server Explorer in Visual Studio to connect to the existing MDF file (Server Explorer => Connect to Database => Microsoft SQL Server Database File). This will create a connection string in your WebAPI project's `Web.config`. However, this will work only locally, because the database is stored as a local file only.

Comment: I used it, but that ask for create local copy in WebAPI project. Therefore we havent gerenal data, if database in WinForms had changed.

Comment: Great, i perhaps did it. And one little question , maybe you know how to get client's country from online-service, if i have ip or hostname?

Comment: Well, IP and hostname are not really reliable. But you can use the `Accept-Language` header to get the user's language, which is usually a very good estimate - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language

Comment: @Ara  If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.